# Given the head of a linked list, rotate the list to the right by k places. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, linked-list

I was trying this code but for some reason, it isn't working. Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong.
I know the correct code is already posted everywhere included here in this platform, I just want to know what is wrong with mine.

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode() {}
 *     ListNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { this.val = val; this.next = next; }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public ListNode rotateRight(ListNode head, int k) {
        
        for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
            ListNode temp=head;
            ListNode last=head;
            
            while(temp.next!=null){
                if(temp.next.next==null) last=temp;
                temp=temp.next;
            }
            
             ListNode dummy=new ListNode(temp.val);
             dummy.next=head;
             last.next=null;
                  
        }
        return head;
                
    }
}
```

Comment: Rotating "right" vs "left" means about as much as going up or down in space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set `dummy.next` to `head`, `dummy` is now the beginning of the list. So you should set `head = dummy`. Such as:

```
class Solution {
    public ListNode rotateRight(ListNode head, int k) {
        if (head == null || head.next == null){
            return head;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
            ListNode temp=head;
            ListNode last=head;
            
            while(temp.next!=null){
                if(temp.next.next==null) last=temp;
                temp=temp.next;
            }
            
             ListNode dummy=new ListNode(temp.val);
             dummy.next=head;
             last.next=null;
             head = dummy;
     
        }
        return head;
                
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I just want to know what is wrong with mine

The fact that you have 2 nested loops is wrong, and the fact that you create a new `ListNode` object is wrong, so the entire concept of your code is wrong.

Think about it. Draw it on paper.

Assuming that rotating right means that the values seem to move right, then e.g. to rotate 3 right on a list that is 9 long, you get:

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
         │
         │ Move 3 right
         ↓
 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

If you look at the changes to the `next` links, you'll see that you only need to do 3 changes, and you're all done:

```
 head
   ↓                                        BEFORE
   1 → 2 → 3 → 4 → 5 → 6 → 7 → 8 → 9

                         head
                           ↓
┌→ 1 → 2 → 3 → 4 → 5 → 6   7 → 8 → 9 ─┐     AFTER
│                                     │
└─────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Actions to take:

- Find node "6" (`newTail`) and last node (`tail`)
- Update last node to point to first node (`tail.next = head`)
- The new head will be the `next` value (`newHead = newTail.next`)
- Clear the `next` value (`newTail.next = null`)

Only the first action is a loop, so the fact that you have 2 *nested* loops is just not the right solution. It can be done with a single loop, even if you don't know the list length, though you might code it using 2 separate (non-nested) loops.

There is absolutely no need to create a new `ListNode` object doing this.

Comment: This is a very good and clearly explained answer.